# Format string with line breaks in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am using Powershell V2.0

I have a string in file:
`"-PatchInfo-" = "-HFInfo-"`

I want `"-HFInfo"` to replace with a string `1234 "-PatchInfo-" = "-HFInfo-"`
. File should look like after replacement:
`"-PatchInfo-" = "1234" 
"-PatchInfo-" = "-HFInfo-"`

I am using command
(gc filename.txt) -replace "-HFInfo-",'1234 `n \"-PatchInfo-\" = \"-HFInfo-\"' | 
Out-File filename.txt

But I am unable to get line break after executing this command.
I tried various other possibilities as well but couldn't make it.
Can anybody suggest what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

```
(gc filename.txt) |% {$_.replace("-HFInfo-","`"-PatchInfo-`" = `"1234`"`r`n`"-PatchInfo-`" = `"-HFInfo-`"")} | Out-File filename.txt
```

Will produce:

```
"-PatchInfo-" = "1234"
"-PatchInfo-" = "-HFInfo-"
```

Comment: Output in file is   "-PatchInfo-" = "1234`r`n \"-PatchInfo-\" = \"-HFInfo-\""  after adding ' before 1234 which u missed in your answer.